# Why does top position only change once

Tags: javascript

I'm having trouble understanding why the following only runs once no matter how many times you click it.

It updates the top position once but on next click it does nothing. Why does it not read the previous top input and add another 10 pixels to it every click?

```js
const text = document.querySelector('.test');

window.onclick = () => {
  text.style.top = (text.style.top += 10) + 'px';
}
```

```css
.test {
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<p class="test">Hello World!</p>
```

Comment: Cause `10px10px` makes little sense.

Comment: Split the px and the numbers before doing arithmetic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use parseInt to extract the numeric part of text.style.top.

```js
const text = document.querySelector('.test');

window.onclick = () => {
  // extract the numeric part from text.style.top
  var t = parseInt(text.style.top, 10);
  // if there was no numeric part assume zero
  if (isNaN(t)) t = 0;
  
  // do the math inside parens, and then append "px" to it
  text.style.top = (t + 10) + "px";
}
```

```css
.test {
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<p class="test">Hello World!</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

Doing math with strings won't work (`"10px" + "10px"` is not `"20px"` ...). Instead keep a number and then convert it to a string:

```
let top = 10;

window.onclick = () => {
  text.style.top = (top += 10) + 'px';
};
```